# How many iOS Certificate addition

Tags: ios

I am unable to add a new iOS cetificate in my member center. iOS app development option is been disabled. Can any one help me to know why is it. And wht is the maximum number of certificate that can be added per account. The below has the screen shot of it[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one certificate for each category that is available on developer account.
This certificate is valid for 1 year.

You can create number of provisioning profiles using this certificate.

Rest other information you can get from [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/gettingstarted/)

Comment: Thankx for the reply, But this account i use already has two iOS Developer certificates. I am confused how is that then possible if we can create only a single developer certificate.

Comment: other certificate must be other than development .